# current requets sql azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

i have a database in azure that throw this error: 
[image: Error]

in azure portal i have 120 current request(in my rate plane) but when i run query to get my current request show only get one current request.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Concurrent_Requests] FROM sys.dm_exec_requests R
```

i need configure in azure portal or need to run some query???
how can get all my current request in my database???

Answer (score 1):

That means that you are out of connections and they are exhausted. Try to see sys.resource_stats view - that will say if you hit any limits that are in place in the case of SQL Azure. And, what is more important, make sure that you open and close your connections explicitly.

Another way could be to use Max Pool Size parameter in your conn string, but according to the error message, i do not think that is gonna to work.

And one of the ways to see if your are hitting any limits, you can try to scale up your SQL Azure from your current mode to more powerful.